# Dot at the end of a glossary entry

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

I Have a strange problem with my glossaries. When you compile the provided example, `pdflatex` adda period for the first and last glossary entry but not for the second. I added the `nopostdot` option to the glossaries package.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dvipsnames]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage[french, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[
    style=super, toc, nopostdot, acronym, ]{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries

\begin{document} 

\newglossaryentry{hypermedia} { 
    name={Hyperm\'edia}, 
    description={Hypermédia est une extension de l'hypertexte à des données 
    multimédias comme des images, sons et vidéos}
}

\newglossaryentry{kanban} { 
name={Kanban}, 
description={La méthode Kanban permet, à l'aide d'un tableau, de visualiser 
    le processus de traitement d'une tâche. Les colonnes du tableau sont les 
    états possibles pour une tâche et chaque colonne contient un nombre 
    maximum prédéfini de tâches simultanées. Les tâches passent alors d'un 
    état à un autre selon l'avancement de projet}
}

\newglossaryentry{monkeypatching} { 
    name={Monkey patching},
    description={\textit{Monkey patching} est une façon de modifier ou 
    d'étendre du code sans modifier le code source original. Ceci est 
    possible avec les langages de programmations dynamiques}
}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: result of compilation]

Comment: I get no periods.

Comment: @egreg It's something with my installation then? I tried it in two computers

Comment: Works fine for me as well. What version of `glossaries` do you have installed? (You can find it by searching for `glossaries.sty` in the log file.) If you can, move your definitions (`\newglossaryentry`) to the preamble. There are [known problems](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) with defining entries after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the O.P. used most likely an outdated `glossaries` version (the issue can't be reproduced)

Comment: I can't tell you which version I have as I reinstalled my Ubuntu. It is the version I installed a year ago and I don't know if it was updated by the Ubuntu.